# Modified standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> Find $P(|Z-1/3| < 1)$, $P(Z+Z^2 > 1)$ and $P((e^Z/(2+e^Z))>5/8)$ where $Z \sim  N(0,1)$

I know how to find the probability using the standard normal distribution but I'm not sure how to solve these questions involving modified versions of the standard deviations.

Do I use $|Z-1/3| \sim N(-1/3, 1)$ for the first one and $(Z+Z^2) \sim N(0,2)$ for the second one? For the third one I'm not sure where to even start from.

Answer (score 1):

$P(|Z-1/3|<1) = P(-2/3 < Z < 4/3) = P(Z < 4/3) - P(Z < -2/3)$.

and for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$x + x^2 > 1 \iff x^2 + x -1 > 0$

Find the roots of this polynomial and then you can determine where this inequality is true. Rest is similar to the first part.

(I suppose $N(1,0)$ is the standard normal distribution, it is better to write $N(0,1)$)

Comment: How would this work if we wanted to find $P(0.4<|Z-1/3| <1)$? Also I'm adding another part which I forgot to write earlier.

Comment: $a<|x-c|<b \iff a+c<x<b+c\text{ or } -a+c > x > -b+c$ hence you have two different intervals that inequality holds. (Check the case a=0).